# How do I make Thunderbird automatically mark as spam all emails which have any emoji characters in subject line?

Tags: email, thunderbird, spam-prevention

This year I've started receiving spam emails which are very easily identified by containing emoji symbols in the subject title. I tried filtering them one by one, but the spammers just keep using new ones, so I'm having to constantly add more filters of a single emoji symbol. Is there a way to add all emojis to the filter, existing and planned? Or can I whitelist only alphanumeric characters and characters of certain languages I expect to receive emails in, to achieve basically the same result?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this by installing `FiltaQuilla` from the addons manager and creating a filter with `Subject Regex Match` with the filter `/\p{Extended_Pictographic}/gu`.

This will allow you to target mails with emojis in the title which are in my experience 99% spam.